# Why is the pinyin of these two character is so weird?

Tags: pinyin

話's pinyin is hua instead of wua.

化's pinyin is hua instead of fua.

We see that these two character pronounce differently when we speaks in mandarin.

Why is the pinyin of these two character is so weird?

Comment: Why do you think they should be `wua` and `fua`?

Comment: Their pronounciation should be same as `hua` in `普通话`, do you refer to some kind of dialect?

Comment: @songyuanyao - Cantonese

Comment: Maybe you should change to Cantonese IME.

Comment: What Cantonese pinyin are you expecting?

Comment: 化 Jyutping: faa3 / Yale: fa3

话 Jyutping: waa6 / Yale: wa6

Two major pinyin systems are written this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're reading Mandarin pinyin but expecting Cantonese pinyin.

Cantonese pinyin is like this:

```
化 Jyutping: faa3 / Yale: fa3 

话 Jyutping: waa6 / Yale: wa6
```

and actually it seems to fit what you were expecting!